# Socket io socket won't carry jwt token in angular factory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, mean-stack

I am trying socket.io authorization with jwt in my MEAN stack project. I have problem about socket object won't carry jwt token after I log out and relog in.

when I  log in , token will store in local storage

```
    UsersSvc.login($scope.user).success(function(data){
        if (data.success) {
            store.set('jwt', data.token);
    }
```

then angular socket factory will retrieve jwt from local storage and send to server

```
.factory('SocketSvc',[ 'store',
 function (store) {
  this.initSocket = function(){
     return io.connect('http://localhost:3000',{ query : 'token='  + store.get('jwt')});
 };

 var socket = this.initSocket();

 return {
   on: function (eventName, callback) {
    socket.on(eventName, function () {  
     var args = arguments;
     $rootScope.$apply(function () {
      callback.apply(socket, args);
    });
  });
},
 emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
   socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
     var args = arguments;
     $rootScope.$apply(function () {
       if (callback) {
         callback.apply(socket, args);
       }
     });
   })
 },
};
```

however; after I logged out

```
$scope.logout = function(){
    var account = UsersSvc.currentAccount();
    SocketSvc.emit('logout', { account : account});
    $state.go('anon.login');
};
```

then jwt toke will be remove from local storage

```
 if (toState.name == "anon.login") {
        store.remove('jwt');
```

when I log in agin, token in socket query is gone while you logged in successfully. I am dealing with this problems several days. I don't know what happened.

The only way let server get token again is that refresh the page agin manually.
or close the tab and open a new page then log in agin.

My assumption is the problem of angular factory since it is singleton that it's can't be modified.

I don't know it is right or wrong or how to solve the problem. If you have any suggestion. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by wrapping the initSocket code into a function in the return block
you are right in pointing that token is null as the user is not logged in.

```
this.initSocket = function(){
     return io.connect('http://localhost:3000',{ query : 'token='  + store.get('jwt')});
 };

 var socket = this.initSocket();
```

the above should go inside return block and called once in any Controller for initializing the socket with a valid token

My soultion:

```
angular.module('mean1App')
  .factory('socket', function(socketFactory, $rootScope, Auth) {
    var socket = null;
    return {
      socket: socket,

      init: function(){
            var ioSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000', {
              // Send auth token on connection, you will need to DI the Auth service above
              'query': 'token=' + Auth.getToken(),
              path: '/socket.io-client'
            });

            socket = socketFactory({
              ioSocket: ioSocket
            });
      },
...
...blah 
  });
```